# Rails Best Practices false positive unused methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, false-positive, rbp

I'm using Rails best practices to validate my own code.

```
./app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (NewsItemsController#new)
./app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (NewsItemsController#create)
./app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (NewsItemsController#edit)
./app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (NewsItemsController#update)
./app/controllers/news_items_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (NewsItemsController#destroy)
./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (PagesController#new)
./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (PagesController#create)
./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (PagesController#edit)
./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (PagesController#update)
./app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (PagesController#destroy)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#update)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:8 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#after_sign_up_path_for)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#new)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#create)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#edit)
./app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:1 - remove unused methods (RegistrationsController#destroy)
./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (StaticController#new)
./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (StaticController#create)
./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (StaticController#edit)
./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (StaticController#update)
./app/controllers/static_controller.rb:2 - remove unused methods (StaticController#destroy)
```

The actions here are mostly unused methods. The only problem is that those actions aren't even defined... I tried to use `remove_method` without any success.

for example, news_items_controller only has `index` and `show` while the routes define only `index` and `show`.

My class is defined as following: `NewsItemsController << StaticController << ApplicationController << ActionController::Base`

My guess is that ActionController::Base is defining them, funny thing is that it's not showing "ApplicationController"...

here is the content of StaticController

```
# encoding: utf-8                                                                                                                                                                                     
class StaticController < ApplicationController
end
```

And no route is pointing to `StaticController`.

And routes.rb

```
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /ru|en/ do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

    resources :news_items, only: [:show, :index]
    resources :pages, :only => [:show]

    root to: "home#index"
  end

  root to: "home#index"
```

Comment: Do you have any routes like `resources :items` or `resources :news_items` in your `routes.rb`?

Comment: why would I remove that, rails-best-practices is the name of the program. I'm not asking for best practices...it just happen that the program is called that way

Comment: @rekire https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices

Comment: What happens if you remove the `resources` routes, do the messages go away?

Answer (score 4):

Rails best practises often indulge in showing false positives.
In such cases, I would not trust too much on RBP and go ahead and exclude the actions altogether in rails_best_practises.yml file.

for example :

```
RemoveUnusedMethodsInControllersCheck: { except_methods: ['YourController#search'] }
```